# Svg rendering in WebView is pixelated on iPad3

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, webview, svg, titanium

I am using the Titanium SDK for developing a mobile application (for the iPad). On iPad1 and iPad2 everything is fine. But on the iPad3 my Svg graphics were drawn ugly. I am dealing with a lot of WebView's in different size's to show the Svg's. Some WebView's did the rendering as it should be, but in some WebView's the Svg looks like a scaled png or jpg. The Svg's were created on demand and were embedded into html. The Svg styling is done by CSS.

I've no idea why this happen...?

Help from you would be awesome!

THX Tass

Link to a screenshot
[enter link description here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/69839046/IMG_0039.PNG)

Comment: Screenshots would really be helpful here.

Comment: Have you checked the resolutions of the svg files?

Comment: Good hint, the pixelated svg could be because of the different resoltions from the iPad's. I created the app for iPad2 and installed it later on an iPad, too. The app works without any scaling issues, only the svg looks wrong scaled. I will check this, thanks.

Comment: These SVG thumbnails would be a good candidate for rasterisation, I should think - they will render more quickly too.

Comment: I solved the problem. It's the css shadow from the WebView which causes the pixalation on iPad3. After removing the shadow, the svg was absolutly sharpe :) Thx for your help!